# Escaping my own regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that replaces matched content with other content from a larger body of text.

> This is [5] content

So in this example, the regex looks for anything in '[]' and replaces it with content determined by '5', lets say a string from a table with an index of 5.

Here is the regex I am using:

```
/(?<!/)\[(.*?)\]?\]/
```

Theres a few extra bracket checks for other functionality, and there is a look behind right now that is excluding any tag preceded by '/'

What I want to do, is when a tag is escaped with / it will remove the escape character and move on the the next match.

So:

> This is /[5] content

becomes:

> This is [5] content

as opposed to:

> This is [5] content

becoming:

> This is [insert content here] content

I hope that's not too confusing.

The way I'm currently replacing my matched content is with a recursive function that finds the first match, replaces it, updates the original material, and then calls it's self until there are no matches left. This is probably the source of my problem, but I could not figure out another way of doing it. If I preg_match all the matches once and loop through each, updating the original content, then the position of the matched tags changes from when preg_match was run and everything gets mixed up.

Heres a paste of the function in question http://pastebin.com/ckVXNaxt

Comment: Why don't you replace all desired chunks first and then try to remove preceded characters like `/`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would work, but that would be running two matches, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) which seems to suit my needs well

```
return preg_replace_callback( $tagRegex, function($matches){
  //if match starts with '/' remove slash and return
  //otherwise do logic
}
,$content);
```

My finished product http://pastebin.com/qJ1g0pPq

Comment: Be careful when you say `Here is the regex I am using: /(?<!/)\[(.*?)\]?\]/` As a regex, this will not match anything at all. Specifically, you tell the engine to match `/` then _not_ match it `(?<!/)` which is a contradiction. If you're using the forward slash as a delimiter, then it's _not_ part of the regex and it can't be parsed the way it is.